# Convert a searchable PDF to searchable PDF/A using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, searchable, pdfa

I am using Ghostscript to convert PDF to PDF/A by command line:

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile="output.pdf" input.pdf
```

But output file lost searchable text property.

How can I obtain searchable PDF/A files as output ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied an input file to look at, nor mentioned which version of Ghostscript you are using.

Let me start with my standard lecture on this subject; when you take a PDF file as input, and use Ghostscript's pdfwrite device to produce a new PDF file, you are **NOT** 'converting', 'editing' or 'modifying' the input file.

What happens is that the PDF interpreter interprets the PDF file, and produces a series of graphcs primitives, which it feeds to the graphics library. This then processes these primitives, and passes them to the device. The device then emits them to the output file. In the case of a rendering device (eg TIFF) it renders theoperation to a bitmap and when it reaches the end of file, it writes the bitmap as a file. In the case of pdfwrite, it re-assembles these primtives into a brand new PDF file.

So the output PDF file has nothing in common with the input PDF file, **except** its appearance.

There are disadvantages to this approach (it does limit us in preserving some non-printing aspects of the input file), but there are also advantages; for instance it permits us to alter colour spaces, flatten transparency, change font encodings etc.

In addition to this you have chosen to create a PDF/A file. PDF/A limits the available features of the PDF specification, and it may be (its impossible to tell without seeing the original file) that it simply isn't possible to represent the original PDF file as a PDF/A file without altering some aspects of it.

Again, without seeing the original file I can tell, but it may be that you simply cannot achieve what you want, or at least not using Ghostscript.

Comment: Actually, some inputs files return correct (correct means wanted) outputs. I realized that my problems occur with input PDFs that were made with DOMPDF, by HTML to PDF process. I gonna continuing researching about it and making tests. Thanks for attention.